# Shrink range of numbers from the end

Tags: python, math

I need help how can i calculate this result?

```
for test in range(6):
    math = 3*test
    math1 = 141593*test


    print(math,round(math1))

3,141593
6,283186
```

i search output
something to `round`

```
3,14
6,28

if 5+ 
6,285186
output search is 6,29
```

ect...
all attempts make me mistake

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you not use the built-in `round` function?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work so I need to modify the whole code @d.b

Comment: TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: anyone to help me or should I fix the question?

Comment: Since both `math` and `math1` are integers, `round` won't do anything.

Comment: @AKX yes but then I put in one number / and there is a rest at the back
3.141593  and I want to use it round but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since both `math` and `math1` are integers, `round` won't do anything.
Do you maybe want to just slice the "decimal" part to 2 characters?

```
for i in range(6):
    a = 3 * i
    b = 141593 * i
    print(a, str(b)[:2], sep=",")
```

This prints out

```
0,0
3,14
6,28
9,42
12,56
15,70
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not increase according to previous figures
if greater than 5 = +1

Comment: if 5+ 
6,285186
output search is 6,29

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
for i in range(1,6+1):
    a = 3.141593 * i
    print(a)
    print(round(a,2), sep=",")
```